# View document from solution in bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in my application and I am trying to use the modal window to display my documents. I am able to display another web page or page in my application but not sure if I can or if it is event possible to display a document in a modal window.

By document I mean word document, video or powerpoint for example that are in a folder in my .net solution.

The code for a modal window is the following:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".document">Document</a>

<div class="modal fade document" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content nobg" style="width:650px">
            <iframe id="pptframe" width="100%" height="500" style="border: none;"  src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://testprojects.net/project.docx&embedded=true" ></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This example using a document that would be on my google drive (doesn't actually display the document in example code) but I thought that I could just replace the source with the file in my solution and it would embed in the window but this did not work.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Google has an option to publish to web with embed code. Did you do that? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/143345

Comment: yes that does work but I need to use files in my solution not from the web.